# What happens in the PHP backend when the client stops loading page while script is executed?

Tags: php, client

When the client is leaving a website while its loading, what happend with the not executed php code? Example:

```
<?php

// insert something in the database

// user leaves the page / is closing the browser

// insert again something in the database

// echo something

?>
```

I read, that the whole script **always** is executed, until then something is sent to the client (e.g. echo "sdasdasd"). Is that correct?

Comment: Because all PHP code is executed on SERVER once called it will finish all its tasks. At your code PHP will echo something but there wont be anyone to see that echo :)

Comment: okay so I dont have to be scared that only the half of my script (and my database action!) is executed? this would namly end in a big mess ;)

Comment: Svetlio's comment is not correct - the PHP process can exit before completing in some cases if the client (e.g. web browser) closes the connection.

Answer (score 2):

The script will be terminated as soon as PHP detects that the client is disconnected (usually when it tries to output something). So normally you don't have a guarantee that the script will finish it's work - you either have to say that the script should continue even if the connection is closed, or if there is something important to do at the end of the script, put it in a [shutdown function](http://php.net/register_shutdown_function)
 See [Connection Handling](http://php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php) and [ignore_user_abort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php) for more information

Comment: I also found ignore_user_abort, but there is the problem that I am using the shutdown function for error handling (saving errors in db etc.) and I dont know how those both functions work together...

Comment: You can check the connection status inside your shutdown function